# How to solve $\cos x - \cosh y=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can we solve this problem $\cos x - \cosh y=0$
Is it correct that only happen if and only if $x=y=0$ is there any solution?

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions only, or also complex ones?

Comment: Even if we restrict to real $x$, the periodic nature of cosine gives additional solutions.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I'm an idiot, sorry. Just realised after posting...

Comment: @nathan.j.mcdougall: I was first to make a dumb comment in this thread.

Answer (score 8):

Since $\cosh y\gt1$ if $y\not=0$ and $\cos x\le1$ for all $x$, you *must* have $y=0$ in any solution.  After that all you need is $\cos x=1$, which is satisfied by $x=2\pi n$ for any integer $n$.  So the complete solution set is $\{(2\pi n,0)\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: What about complex solutions?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, I am assuming the OP is tacitly assuming $x$ and $y$ are real.  If he asks about complex solutions, I'll edit accordingly (or let someone else answer).

Comment: I was just curious to know myself haha.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x\le 1$ while $\cosh y\ge 1$. The only solution is $x\equiv 0\mod 2\pi,\enspace y=0$.

Comment: @Barry  Many thanks Barry and Bernard for your help. It is clear for me now. How about if $\pm \cosh x= \cosh yu/2$?

Comment: Where does the ± come from? $\cosh x\ge 1$  for all $x$!

Comment: In that case, it has solutions only if $\cos z=1$ and the solutions are $x=\pm\dfrac{yu}2$.